# Attaching multiple elements in a HTML page to single jQuery file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I would like to create a single jQuery js file which would handle multiple events happening in a given page for e.g.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/jquery/pagehandler.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $("body").pageHandler();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class"highlight-on-mouseover">
    <tr>Test row to be highlighted on mouse over</tr>
    </table>
    <div class="disappear-on-click">Test Div to disappear</div>
<a href="/pageaccess" class="retrieve-using-ajax">Load information from linked page to the next div</a>
<div>Load linked data here</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Instead of writing multiple `on()` functions I would like to unify everything in one pageHandler file to allow for re-usage.
How can this be achieved.

Comment: Where are the `on()`? Can you show what's in the pagehandler.js file?

Comment: You can pass through `data` attribute the params that will change

Comment: Depends on what 'events' you are trying to handle (given that you've not provided any information).  You'll find that a single "generic" event handler will very quickly becomes a huge unmaintainable mess.